# How do I prepopulate my Room database?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

It is my first time experimenting with Room database and I want to pre populate the database with 20 User objects. But the code I'm using adds 20 more users to the existing list everytime it runs. How do I keep it from doing that?

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
public abstract DataExchange dataExchange();

public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(final Context context){
    if (INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                "User_Database")
                .addCallback(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull final SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getAppDatabase(context).dataExchange().insert(User.populate());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public static void destroyInstance(){
    INSTANCE = null;
}
```

Here's the User class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
public class User{

public User(String name){
    setName(name);
}

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int uid;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Username")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setUid(int uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public static User[] populate(){
    User[] ar = new User[20];
    for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
        ar[i] = new User("USER "+(i+1));
    }
    return ar;
}
}
```

Also, where I took the code from had a getInstance(context) instead of getAppDatabase(context) inside run(). I changed it because getInstance was found in 5 libraries I didn't know about.

Here's DataExchange :

```
@Dao
public interface DataExchange {

@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table")
List<User> getAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table where username LIKE  :name ")
User findByName(String name);

@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from user_table")
int countUsers();

@Update
void update(User user);

@Insert
void insertAll(User... users);

@Delete
void delete(User user);

}
```

Comment: Use `@Entity` and `@Dao` , In Entity there should be a primary key which will be unique for each user

Comment: @Redman there is an int variable  and a String value for each user. int variable is the primary key.

Comment: Will int variable be same for user when app is killed and opened again ?

Comment: It should stay the same. Won't it? That's why I'm using the database.

Comment: where are you getting users from ? are you creating in app or getting from server ?

Comment: No the User class has the function populate() which supplies 20 users as a list.

Comment: can you add that method in question

Comment: Did that. Please have a look again.

Comment: You're hiding a lot of code from us. What does your User class and dataExchange() method look like?

Comment: @ZUNJAE I added the the DataExchange class now. Please take a look again.

Comment: Again, why are you hiding the User class from us? Is there anything private in there you don't want us to see?

Comment: Add User class too

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that what I mentioned was enough. Please take a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Add a primary key to your Entity, it's recommended to use an int in your scenario. For example: User with ID 1 is unique in your database.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

**Step 2:**

Assign a value to the id variable. I recommend assigning it through the constructor of the User class (mainly to prevent it from being 0, or to prevent you forgetting to assign it later in a setter)

**Step 3:**

Define a conflict strategy in your @Insert (that's in your DAO class). What do you want your database to do when it tries to add anohter User with an id = 1? Do you want to delete the older User? Just ignore it?

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
 public void insertUsers(User... users);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert

Also, I'm 100% sure you're guessing code. Just look up the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. All this time I had been thinking that the error was only in the AppDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to just copy database which you created using DB Browser for SQLite. It is the easiest way to do prepopulating. You just create **Assets** folder in your app, add folder databases and after that copy your database.
In singleton class where you are creating your database just add **createFromAsset()** method and you have your pre-populated database. Photo is on that link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5o4v.jpg

Also in this article is described very well.
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/packing-the-room-pre-populate-your-database-with-this-one-method-333ae190e680